# Is there anyway to let client change render distance bigger than server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends join my server and it's great. But due to my potato computer, I can't set render distant more than 7 and we found out my setting affect them
So is there anyway I can let them change their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server does not load chunks, then the clients can't see them. The other players can definitely set their render distance farther, but the only benefit they get from that is that the fog is farther away.

There are mods that keep a cache of currently not loaded chunks, for example "Bobby": https://www.modrinth.com/mod/bobby
Note that this can lead to strange effects when chunks are visible, but don't update.

You could run a dedicated server on your computer with a higher render distance, but then everything that happens in it would of course still need to be calculated by your computer. It might be worth it if you then set your client's render distance much lower or use a separate computer for it.

1.18 also added a "simulation distance" option, both for servers and for Singleplayer worlds (so it should also work for LAN sharing). If the render distance is higher than the simulation distance, then further out chunks are loaded and can be seen by clients, but do not do anything: Mobs don't move, contraptions don't update, water doesn't flow, etc.

Comment: Bobby is such a mid. https://www.modrinth.com/mod/bobby

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the answer! And also 1.18's "simulation distance" option, which does something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer your world to his PC. Then he can share it with you on LAN, and your potato PC won't suffer

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible, they will be able to change it in their configuration, but in the end the one that has to render it all will be the computer where the server is hosted, if it's yours and can't render more than 7 chunks, their game is not going to go better.

There are many free host server that you and your friends can use, and thanks to that your computer would work better, so they could connect to the server without you having the server on.

You can also use the LAN option, you can pass the files of the world to your friend and he host the server on his computer.

Comment: Please don't advertise in posts. And server hosting can easily be done on a private computer as well. If LAN play is an option, then it's even easy to connect to it.

Comment: Okey sorry. My intention was not to announce, I'm sorry, it was just an example.